# image onclick() function to display dailog window with form details

Tags: javascript, html

Hers is the code i written for functionality , when click on image, dailog window should load with form input elements. Please look into the below code and let me know where i did mistake.

code:-

```
            <dialog id="login" style="border-color: blue; border: 1px solid">
                <form name="reg">
                First Name : <input type="text" name="fname" required>
                Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" required>
                Email <input type="email" name="mail" required>
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass" required>
                Confirm Password : <input type="password" name="confpass" required>
                <button type="submit"></button>
                <button type="reset"></button>
                </form>
            </dialog>

        <script>
            function registration(){

                var dailog = document.getElementById('login');
                dailog.open();
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) there are `.show()` and `.showModal()` methods - there's no `.open()` method.

Comment: Thank you Radoslaw. by using show(). it is displaying. but do not have any close icon in that dialog window how to do that. Instead of dialog window ,can replace with popup window with same code.

Comment: From where do you get that there will be a close button if you use open() ?

Comment: You have to create the closing button by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> dailog.open();

to

> dailog.open = true;

as

> show

is property, not a function